# How to solve cv2.error: (-215)?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
  break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've got this error

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in
>   imshow, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 325
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File "2.py", line 9, in 
>   cv2.imshow('frame',frame) cv2.error:
>   /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:325: error: (-215)
>   size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

I've already try changing the '0' on `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to '1' and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when `cap.read()` returns empty frame for some reason. Solve this with:

```
while(True):
    result, frame = cap.read()
    if result:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```